# Controlling an Animate CC animation in javascript

Tags: animate-cc

With Adobe Animate CC - is there a way to control Symbols from a javascript file?

For example,

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-octo");
exportRoot = new lib.octo();

stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
stage.addChild(exportRoot);
stage.update();
exportRoot.gotoAndStop(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method does actually work, I just hadn't realised that the frames start at 0 instead of 1